# Some problems finding specific Words in Text

Tags: regex, python-2.7, findall

iam new in Python and have some easy questions (but they are killing me).

I want a code that shows me the words after an "Dr.", but only, if the follwoing word is title, like Bernard in "Dr. Bernard". The same i need for numerous other stuff, like "med." and so on...

Here my code:

```
    sentence = "Dr. Mobuis is a good person. Dr. med. Peter isnt."
    for m in re.finditer("(Dr\.|med\.)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)", sentence):
         print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
```

Well, now i get:

```
    00-10: Dr. Mobuis
    33-43: med. Peter
```

I want to get rid of that "Dr." and "med.". How? Or is there an better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print the group index 2 instead of group index 0.

```
>>> for m in re.finditer("(Dr\.|med\.)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)", sentence):
...     print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(2))
... 
00-10: Mobuis
33-43: Peter
```

**Update:**

```
>>> for m in re.finditer("(Dr\.|med\.)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)\s\S+", sentence):...     print '%02d-%02d: %s - context is %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(2),m.group(0))
... 
00-13: Mobuis - context is Dr. Mobuis is
33-49: Peter - context is med. Peter isnt.
```

Comment: Thanks! I can be really stupid sometimes. Thanks. That solved at least the problem with the Dr. and med.

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the context of Mobuis and Peter? Right now i get the index, but what if i want the context? Something like "00-10: Mobuis - context is 'Dr. Mobius is'. The word before and the word after?

Comment: context means? What would be the result to be?

Comment: The word before and the word after, maybe? Something like: "00-10: Mobuis - context is 'Dr. Mobius is'"

Comment: could you edit your expected with the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understand you there. What do you want me to edit where?!

Comment: But now i have to change that line here: <<print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(2))>> or?

Comment: Hmm i get the same output as before: 00-10: Mobuis
33-43: Peter

Comment: change your input string to `"00-10: Mobuis - context is 'Dr. Mobius is'"`

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it. :-( Iam not sure if i explained it right. My input ist: `sentence = "Dr. Mobuis is a good person. Dr. med. Peter isnt."` And now i need to get something like `"00-10: Mobuis - context is 'Dr. Mobius is'" and "33-43: Peter - context is 'med. Peter isnt'"`.

Comment: You helped me a lot, thanks for that! But i still dont get it, that with the context. I get nothing in Version 2.

Comment: i'm also running version 2(2.7).

Comment: Hmmm me2 (2.7.8). How does the complete code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=Dr.)\s*(\b[A-Z]\w+\b)
```

Try this.Grab the match.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/75

Comment: it would be better if you add the corresponding python code.

Comment: Hmm i dont know what iam doing wrong, but i do not get any output?!